# Как сделать массив из объектов, заполненных из двух ArrayList-ов? Для заполнения ListView

Tags: java, android, массивы, listview, arraylist

У меня есть два ArrayList-a: swedishPractice и englishPractice.
В одном - шведские слова, во втором - их переводы на английский.
Они изначально в нужном порядке, и английский перевод правильно соответствует шведском слову.

Мне нужно сделать массив, в котором шведское и английское слово "связаны" в один объект,
для того чтобы создать ListView, в котором будут все эти слова и к каждому подписан перевод.

Я создал класс Word:

public class Word {

```
private String swedish;
private String english;

public Word(String swedish, String english) {
    this.swedish = swedish;
    this.english = english;
}

public String getSwedish() {
    return swedish;
}

public void setSwedish(String swedish) {
    this.swedish = swedish;
}

public String getEnglish() {
    return english;
}

public void setEnglish(String english) {
    this.english = english;
}
```

}

Также создал mListView в новом классе:

```
ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.switchList);

    CheckListAdapter adapter = new CheckListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item_layout, /*здесь должно быть название массива, который пытаюсь сделать*/);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

(В list_item_layout предусмотрены 2 textView для шведского и английского слов)

Не могу понять как теперь сделать массив из этих Word-ов (класс Word), содержащих и шведское слово,
и перевод, из двух упомянутых в начала ArrayList-ов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас изначально все слова в исходных массивах в правильном порядке, то можно просто пройтись по одному массиву и синхронно по второму. Например так:

```
ArrayList<Word> finalArray = new ArrayList<Word>();
for (int i = 0; i < englishPractice.size(); i++) {            
    finalArray.add(new Word(englishPractice.get(i),swedishPractice.get(i)));
}
```

по итогу у вас будет массив состоящий из объектов класс `Word`. Дальше вам нужно это как-то отобразить. Судя по тому что у вас есть адаптер, то в его конструктор нужно будет передавать массив слов: `ArrayList<Word> words`

Comment: спасибо. только слово counter андроидСтудио не распознает, наверно вместо него надо написать i ?

Comment: протупил немного)) исправил ответ :)